# Electrical conductivity/resistance of gas or vapor in an electrostatic field at normal temperature and pressure

Tags: electric-fields, electrical-resistance

For liquids (e.g. liquid metal and water), I could find their electrical conductivities (unit in S m$^{-1}$) or resistances in the CRC handbook. Also, I noted that equations for calculating the conductivity of water can be found in literature, please see the following figure for example (please click on the figure to see a clearer one).

[image]

I am wondering if there is an equation for calculating an approximate value of the conductivity of a gas or vapor of a liquid. For most gases, they are acting as dielectrics in a static electric field when the field strength is lower than their dielectric breakdown voltage. Or is there any handbook collects the electrical conductivities of some typical gases other than water vapor? I understand that in normal pressure and temperature, the electrical conductivity of a gas is very small, of the order of $10^{-16}-10^{-15}$ S/cm. But I just want to see some examples of typical gases.

Thank you very much!

Comment: So you want to know the Paschen curve for different gases?

Comment: @ Jon Custer thank you for the information. I just knew Paschen's law is an equation that gives the breakdown voltage between two electrodes in a gas as a function of pressure and gap length. Actually, I need the vapor-phase conductivities of some typical refrigerants, for example, HCFC123.

Comment: For most, there will be no conductivity unless there are free electrons and a field high enough to result in breakdown (ignoring corona current, but there the gas does not conduct, just electrons released from one surface to travel to the other in a field).

Comment: @JonCuster by "no conductivity", did you mean the gas conductivity will be very small if the bulk of the gas is free of charges and the field is not that high to achieve breakdown?

Comment: You will get a few free electrons from thermal excitation (very few, but some) and cosmic rays. The Paschen curve then shows you if the available field will accelerate them enough to give them the energy to strike other gas molecules and liberate more charge carriers, leading to an avalanche breakdown scenario.

Comment: Following what @JonCuster said, if you have charged particles in the gas you can calculate their contribution to conductivity via $\sigma=qn\mu$ where $q,n,\mu$ respectively denote the charge of the particle, density of the charged particle, and its mobility. You may want to look at BOLSIG+: http://www.bolsig.laplace.univ-tlse.fr. You should be able to calculate conductivity values for various gas mixtures.